nonroot user cant connect to mariadb server
I'm running mariadb 15 on ubuntu 22.04.
Until recently, my nonroot user could connect to the mariadb server.
This changed recently. I don't know why.
As a nonroot user, an operation like this:

'mysql -uroot -p[pass]'

... will fail with this error:

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
'/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

The same error will occur if the nonroot user tries to use mysqldump.
